# SwiftUI app freezing when using multiple product identifiers in StoreKit

Tags: swift, swiftui, storekit

I'm currently learning Swift and following some tutorials but I'm stuck on a StoreKit issue.

The code works when I provide a single productIdentifier, but when I provide more than 1 in the Set, the entire app hangs on loading. This is in the iOS Simulator, and on a device. I've got 2 identifiers in the set, and both of these work individually, but not at the same time. My code looks the same as the original tutorial (video) so I don't know where I'm going long.

Entire Store.swift file below. Problem appears to be in the fetchProducts function, but I'm not sure. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

````
import StoreKit

typealias FetchCompletionHandler = (([SKProduct]) -> Void)
typealias PurchaseCompletionHandler = ((SKPaymentTransaction?) -> Void)

class Store: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    @Published  var allRecipes = [Recipe]() {
        didSet {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                for index in self.allRecipes.indices {
                    self.allRecipes[index].isLocked = !self.completedPurchases.contains(self.allRecipes[index].id)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private let allProductIdentifiers = Set(["com.myname.ReceipeStore.test", "com.myname.ReceipeStore.test2"])
    
    private var completedPurchases = [String]()
    
    private var productsRequest: SKProductsRequest?
    private var fetchedProducts = [SKProduct]()
    private var fetchCompletionHandler: FetchCompletionHandler?
    private var purchaseCompletionHandler: PurchaseCompletionHandler?
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        
        startObservingPaymentQueue()
        
        fetchProducts { products in

            self.allRecipes = products.map { Recipe(product: $0) }
        }
    }
    
    private func startObservingPaymentQueue() {
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    }
    
    private func fetchProducts(_ completion: @escaping FetchCompletionHandler) {
            
        guard self.productsRequest == nil else { return }
        fetchCompletionHandler = completion

        productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: allProductIdentifiers)
        productsRequest!.delegate = self
        productsRequest!.start()

    }
    
    private func buy(_ product: SKProduct, competion: @escaping PurchaseCompletionHandler) {
        purchaseCompletionHandler = competion
        
        let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
    }
}

extension Store {
    
    func product(for identififier: String) -> SKProduct? {
        return fetchedProducts.first(where: { $0.productIdentifier == identififier })
    }
    
    func purchaseProduct(_ product: SKProduct) {
        buy(product) { _ in }
    }
}

extension Store: SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            var shouldFinishTransactions = false
            switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchased, .restored:
                completedPurchases.append(transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
                shouldFinishTransactions = true
            case .failed:
                shouldFinishTransactions = true
            case .deferred, .purchasing:
                break
            @unknown default:
                break
            }
            
            if shouldFinishTransactions {
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.purchaseCompletionHandler?(transaction)
                    self.purchaseCompletionHandler = nil
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}

// loading products from the store
extension Store: SKProductsRequestDelegate {
    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        let loadedProducts = response.products
        let invalidProducts = response.invalidProductIdentifiers

        guard !loadedProducts.isEmpty else {
            print("Could not load the products!")
            if !invalidProducts.isEmpty {
                print("Invalid products found: \(invalidProducts)")
            }
            productsRequest = nil

            return
        }
       

        // cache the feteched products

        fetchedProducts = loadedProducts
        
        // notify anyone waiting on the product load (swift UI view)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.fetchCompletionHandler?(loadedProducts)
            self.fetchCompletionHandler = nil
            self.productsRequest = nil
        }
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running all of your requests on the main DispatchQueue, this will block other main queue work until completed. You should consider handling some of these tasks with a custom concurrent queue. This bit of sample code should get the ball rolling.

```
func requestProducts(_ productIdentifiers: Set<ProductIdentifier>, handler: @escaping ProductRequestHandler) {
    // Set request handler
    productRequest?.cancel()
    productRequestHandler = handler
    // Request
    productRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers)
    productRequest?.delegate = self
    productRequest?.start()
}

func requestPrices() {
    // Retry interval, 5 seconds, set this to your liking
    let retryTimeOut = 5.0
    var local1: String? = nil
    var local2: String? = nil
    
    let bundleIdentifier =  Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: bundleIdentifier + ".IAPQueue", attributes: .concurrent)
    // Request price
    queue.async {
        var trying = true
        while(trying) {
            let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
            requestProducts(Set(arrayLiteral: SettingsViewController.pID_1000Credits, SettingsViewController.pID_2000Credits)) { (response, error) in
                local1 = response?.products[0].localizedPrice
                local2 = response?.products[1].localizedPrice
                semaphore.signal()
            }
            // We will keep checking on this thread until completed
            _ = semaphore.wait(timeout: .now() + retryTimeOut)
            if(local2 != nil) { trying = false }
        }
        
        // Update with main thread once request is completed
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.price1 = local1 ?? "$0.99"
            self.price2 = local2 ?? "$1.99"
        }
    }
}

extension SKProduct {
// Helper function, not needed for this example
public var localizedPrice: String? {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    formatter.locale = self.priceLocale
    return formatter.string(from: self.price)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at this. Is there a reason that a single productIdentifier doesn't block the main queue, but adding a second completely locks up the app?